# AngularJS - configure services and $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is quite dummy question, but I can't figure it out. I have some simple module, configure like this:

```
var synergy_module = angular.module('synergy', [])
    .config(function($provide, $routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/s/:id', {templateUrl: 'partials/...', controller: SpecPoolCtrl});
$routeProvider.when('/s', {templateUrl: 'partials/...', controller: SpecPoolCtrl});
$provide.factory('foo', function(){return 1;});    
});
```

Now in SpecPoolCtrl:

```
function SpecificationCtrl($scope, foo,$http, $location, $routeParams) {
   window.console.log($scope.foo());
   ...
}
```

When I run this code, I'm getting

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'foo'
at new SpecificationCtrl (app/js/controllers.js:373:31)
at invoke (app/lib/angular/angular.js:2795:28)
at Object.instantiate (app/lib/angular/angular.js:2805:23)
at $get (app/lib/angular/angular.js:4621:24)
```

Can you help me what's wrong? Or some related example how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it like

```
$provide.factory('foo', function(){
  return 1;
});

function SpecificationCtrl($scope, foo,$http, $location, $routeParams) {
    console.log(foo);
   ...
}
```

This is because `foo` isn't defined in your SpecificationCtrl `$scope`, it's being injected so you can use it by just writing `foo` as mentioned above.

Also, if you were to minify your code, please consider injection array syntax.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9vToXS?p=preview)

Comment: :D I can't believe it is such simple mistake. Thanks